# Recover my SuperVault files

Tags: data-recovery

I had several files saved and encrypted on my Android phone using SuperVault.  I no longer have an Android phone but I do have my SuperVault folder with all the files.  Unfortunately I can't access them because they are encrypted.

Short of getting another Android phone (assuming I can move the files to another phone), is there any other way to recover my files?

Comment: Do you have any idea what the IMEI of your Android device was?

Answer (score 2):

First, try to decrypt the encrypted vault on your PC/Mac using other encryption software (presuming, you've its password & encryption key). The encrypted vaults are generally universally compatible, but not necessarily.

If it doesn't work for you, [setup an Android Emulator](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21831/how-to-test-drive-google-android-on-your-pc-without-buying-a-phone/) (virtual Android phone) using Android SDK. [Enable Android Market in it](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21862/how-to-enable-the-android-market-in-the-google-android-emulator/). Install SuperVault & Dropbox using Market. Use Dropbox to download vault file in its virtual sdcard. Decrypt files & withdraw them using Dropbox.

Comment: According to the info on the play store, it won't be that simple.  Supervault uses the device+password method for its encryption, using the phone's IMEI, in addition to your password, as the keying to its top level encryption.  If you do happen to have the old device's IMEI, [you'll need to patch and recompile](http://blog.codepainters.com/2010/11/20/android-emulator-patch-for-configurable-imei-imsi-and-sim-card-serial-number/) the android emulator to allow you to set the IMEI.  If you don't have it, you're SOL unless you want to try to brute force the ~100 million possible IMEIs per device.